# json schema with one mandatory property and at least one another not typed checked

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I have this object in json which I would like to validate with a json schema

```
"reference": {
    "lookup" : "opportunity",
    "shortreference": 93671,
    "guid": "4bb30c46-20ec-e511-9408-005056862bfb"
}
```

*lookup* property is mandatory, and then I need at least, either *shortreference* or *guid* or both.

```
{
    "reference": {
      "type": "object",
      "description": "opportunity reference",
      "properties": {
        "lookup": {
          "enum": [
            "employee",
            "opportunity",
            "serviceline",
            "account"
          ]
        }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "shortreference": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "guid": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "required": [
        "lookup"
      ]
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**
I fixed my issue using the following schema

```
{
    "reference": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "lookup"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "lookup": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum" : ["opportunity", "employee", "serviceline", "account"]
        }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "shortreference": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "shortreference"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "crmguid": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "crmguid"
          ]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "springim": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "springim"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

but when I have both elements, all input type aren't typed checked:
if "shortreference" : "12345" (a string rather an integer), as soon as the parameter crmguid is provided, the check about type won't be performed. is there a way to force it. (I'm using AJV : https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)

Comment: answered my initial question + re-scoped to types not check for all anyOf properties

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`anyOf` will stop validation as soon as it finds one schema that matches.  It should work as you expect if you pull all of your property declarations into the root of the schema and just have `required` in the `anyOf` schemas.  That way, all properties will get type checked and `anyOf` will stop validation when it finds at least one of the required properties.

```
{
  "reference": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["lookup"],
    "properties": {
      "lookup": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum" : ["opportunity", "employee", "serviceline", "account"]
      },
      "shortreference": { "type": "integer" },
      "crmguid": { "type": "string" },
      "springim": { "type": "integer" }
    },
    "anyOf": [
      { "required": ["shortreference"] },
      { "required": ["crmguid"] },
      { "required": ["springim"] }
    ]
  }
}
```